# Why can't i get all the document from a collection in my Firestore Database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I was trying to get documents from Firestore with query but even though my collection has 20 documents I can only get 8.
With the code below only 8 log messages was shown:

```
mFStore.collection("In")
        .orderBy("Time of submit", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)
        .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Time of submit",startDateTimeStamp)
        .whereLessThanOrEqualTo("Time of submit",endDateTimeStamp)
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                List<DocumentSnapshot> snapshotList = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments();
                for(DocumentSnapshot snapshot: snapshotList){
                    Timestamp timestamp = (Timestamp) snapshot.getData().get("Time of submit");
                    Date date = timestamp.toDate();
                    String day = format.format(date);
                    String strQty = snapshot.get("Quantity").toString();
                    Log.d(TAG ,day + " ," + strQty);
                }

            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG ,e.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

With the code below, I've tried removing all the 3 queries from above but I still was only getting 15 log messages.

```
mFStore.collection("In")
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                List<DocumentSnapshot> snapshotList = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments();
                for(DocumentSnapshot snapshot: snapshotList){
                    Timestamp timestamp = (Timestamp) snapshot.getData().get("Time of submit");
                    Date date = timestamp.toDate();
                    String day = format.format(date);
                    String strQty = snapshot.get("Quantity").toString();
                    Log.d(TAG ,day + " ," + strQty);
                }

            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.d(TAG ,e.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

Here is a picture of my database:
[my_database_structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkvu8.png)

Can someone tell me if I'm actually getting all the document but somehow not getting all the logs or am I just not getting all my documents?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Please also show us the simplest query that you're using that doesn't return the data you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't know I needed to add [indexes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jI1ra.png) for the queries. After I added them, I managed to get all the documents I wanted.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).